# Assistance required with coroutines in roblox studio

Tags: lua, coroutine, roblox

I'm trying to make multiple enemies move at once so I'm trying to use coroutines to do it. However, I keep getting this error: "ServerScriptService.Main.Mob:28: invalid argument #1 to 'wrap' (function expected, got nil)"

```
local mob = {}
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")


function mob.Move(mob, map)
local humanoid = mob:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local waypoints = map.Waypoints

for waypoint=1, #waypoints:GetChildren() do
    humanoid:MoveTo(waypoints[waypoint].Position)
    humanoid.MoveToFinished:Wait()
end

mob:Destroy()


end

function mob.Spawn(mob, map, amount)
local mobExists = ServerStorage.Mobs:FindFirstChild(mob)
if mobExists then
    for i=1, amount do
        task.wait(.5)
        local newMob = mobExists:Clone()
        newMob.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = map.Start.CFrame
        newMob.Parent = map.Mobs

        coroutine.wrap(mob.Move)(newMob, map)
    end
else
    warn("No exist ", mob)
end


end

return mob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local variable

```
local mob = {}
```

was shadowed by the function parameter with the same name:

```
function mob.Spawn(mob, map, amount)
```

Thats why `mob.Move` is `nil`